# Can i use NFC for File Transfer in Motorola X?

Tags: nfc, moto-x

My friend is using Motorola X with NFC, but he can't transfer files through it. How do you transfer files through NFC on Android?

Comment: Please edit your question so that it is more clear about what you are asking

Comment: @EthanZ...now can you tell me?

Comment: You're asking how to use NFC to send files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, but you have to use Android Beans

Check [this](http://forums.androidcentral.com/moto-x-2013/311680-nfc-transfer-pics-moto-x-s3.html) forum if you would like more info

Comment: got it...thanx!!